# Trying to get pop up pictures for phone list in Excel

Tags: excel-2003, excel, vba

I have a simple phone list with columns in the form of Name, Address, Phone#, etc.
On the last column I'd like to have the equivalent of a comment rollover which would automatically pop up the persons photo (there are many who only come to this group occasionally, and this would be a help in recognizing them and remembering their names)

1) I have tried to change the comment box Shapes property, but of course there is no msoPicture shape type.

2) I tried to place the picture in the cell and make it clickable, and then to click it again to make it collapse.  But identifying the source picture to change its scalewidth has stumped me.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out an answer.  Place the picture in a tiny format in the cell adjacent to the person's name, and assign the following macro to it.  All of the pictures point to the same macro.  clicking on thepicture toggles it large/small.

```
Sub Picture_Magnify_Click()
  With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    If .Height < 20 Then
      .Height = .Height * 4
      Else
      .Height = .Height / 4
      End If

    End With
  End Sub
```